# Python how to schedule a time like 22:00 - 22:30 and do the specific job?

Tags: time, schedule

Like the topic says, how to do it?
I am planning to do it like this:

1) At 22:00, start printing("I'm working...") and stop at time 22:30

https://pypi.org/project/schedule/
I checked this and tested things out but I didn't get anywhere close to the answer I wanted :(.

Comment: what exactly is not working ?

Comment: `while true:` check the time, if it is between 22:00 and 22:30, print "I'm working", `sleep(60)`. What's the problem?

Comment: how do check the time between 22:00 and 22:30? Do I have to use Datetime module for that?